# Calculating 95% confidence interval for survey results

Tags: confidence-interval, python, inference

I have two columns, column one shows the number of people who reported eating 5 fruits a day, column two shows the number of people who reported eating 5 fruits a day after the second test. Both these values are from a random sample of the population.

I would like to return both the rate of people who started eating 5 fruits a day between test 1 and test 2 and the confidence interval. I always assumed calculating the CI requires the mean and standard deviation, but not sure what the mean would be in the scenario

Here is a sample of my data

```
test1       test2
no           yes
no           yes   
no            no 
yes          yes 
yes          yes
no            no
yes          yes
no            no
yes          yes
no            no
no            no
no            no
```

I would

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure what exactly is asked in this scenario, but I assume you want to know how confidence interval can be calculated in such a scenario. You first take the binary (yes/no) data for each sample (row in your table) to be "yes" if that person started taking 5 fruits after test 1 (that is, had "no" in first column and "yes" in second) and "no" otherwise.

Now simply, you just need to find the proportion of 'yes'-es, which try to estimate the proportion of 'yes'-es in the population for which you can have a confidence interval. If $p$ is the proportion of 'yes'-es in the population, you can calculate $\hat p = \text{number of 'yes'-es}/\text{total samples}$ from your sample to estimate $p$ and calculate a confidence interval for that estimation $[\hat p - \epsilon, \hat p + \epsilon]$.

Have a look at [this](https://opentextbc.ca/introbusinessstatopenstax/chapter/a-confidence-interval-for-a-population-proportion/) link here and the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) page.